# .TIFF image not rendering correctly when saved + R + ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tiff, figure

I'm trying to save an image in the .TIFF format using ggplot in R.

The image saves ok but for some reason it is rendering with white lines up and down the bar, this is not the case in the preview window. See examples below:

Preview:

[image]

TIFF:

[image]

This is the code I used to produce the figure:

```
slc <- ggplot(lslrec, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = 0.5) +  ylab("Complete Submissions") + xlab("") + ggtitle("") +
  theme_apa( legend.use.title = FALSE,
             legend.font.size = 14,
             x.font.size = 14,
             y.font.size = 16,
             facet.title.size = 12,) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=14, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size=14, face = "bold")) + 
  scale_fill_grey(labels=c("Hybrid","EDCS")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Hybrid","EDCS"))
slc

ggsave("Sleep Complete.tiff", slc,  scale = 0.95, dpi = 300)
```

Has anybody else had this issue? I can't find any other examples.

Comment: You are stacking lots of little bars on top of each other, hence the lines. You only see them on the TIFF because it is higher resolution. To avoid this, summarize your data first - try `library(dplyr); lslrec %>% group_by(variable) %>% summarize(value = sum(value)) -> plot_df` and substitute `lslrec` for `plot_df` in your ggplot call

Answer (score 0):

As Allan helpfully pointed out in the comments the issue is that I wasn't grouping the data before creating the barchart. So it was in fact stacking 100s of little bars on top of each other which only became visible in the .TIFF format due to the very high resolution.

I was able to address by using his suggestion. With one additional line to drop NAs, the full working code is:

```
plot_df <- lslrec %>% 
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarize(value = sum(value))

slc <- ggplot(plot_df, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = 0.5) +  ylab("Complete Submissions") + xlab("") + ggtitle("") +
  theme_apa( legend.use.title = FALSE,
             legend.font.size = 14,
             x.font.size = 14,
             y.font.size = 16,
             facet.title.size = 12,) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=14, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size=14, face = "bold")) + 
  scale_fill_grey(labels=c("Hybrid","EDCS")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Hybrid","EDCS"))
slc

ggsave("Sleep Complete.tiff", slc,  scale = 0.95, dpi = 300)
```